# jQuery Slider slides one step too far

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I couldn't find a solution to this problem I'm having with the default jQuery slider and outputting the current value:

It seems like the value is the one from the "previous" step.
With a min value of 0, a max value of 10 and step of 0.25 the most left position displays a value of 0.25 and the most right 9.75 - which is simply wrong.

Does anyone know why this is or how to fix it?

HTML:

```
<div id="slider"></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    value: 2.5,
    step: 0.25
});
$('#slider').on('slide', function( event, ui ) {
    var value = $('#slider').slider('option','value');
    console.log(value);
});
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: What version of jquery-ui are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `ui.value` to get the value of the slider:

```
$('#slider').on('slide', function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.value);
});
```

If you want to see just the value where it stops, and not every value that the slider passes by, use the stop event:

```
$('#slider').on('slidestop', function( event, ui ) {
    console.log(ui.value);
});
```

See http://api.jqueryui.com/slider/#event-stop

Answer (score 0):

Got it!

the "slide" event needs to be called in the slide function:

```
$('#slider').slider({
    min: 0,
    max: 10,
    value: 2.5,
    step: 0.25,
    slide: function( event, ui ) {
        value = ui.value;
        console.log(value);
    }
});
```

Comment: That works also, but moving it from an event handler to the slider initialization isn't what fixed it.  This code works because you used `ui.value`.  Glad you got it working!